# NSTextStorage subclass crash upon removing characters

Tags: ios, nstextstorage

I have a subclass of NSTextStorage that's giving me some issues. I'm getting a crash every time I do the following:

1. Enter some text on the first line
2. Hit return to move to the next line
3. Enter at least two characters
4. Hit backspace

The error I'm getting is `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The index -4097 is invalid'`

The real problem is that I can't trace the error back to any of my own code. The furthest I can get by debugging is that `super.processEditing` inside the override of `processEditing` gets called. The stacktrace isn't giving me anything to work with either.

EDIT: Did some more testing and found out that this only occurs on iOS 9 and newer. Anything on 8 or below doesn't crash.

```
override func attributesAtIndex(location: Int, effectiveRange range: NSRangePointer) -> [String : AnyObject] {
    return backingStore.attributesAtIndex(location, effectiveRange: range)
}

override func replaceCharactersInRange(range: NSRange, withString str: String) {
    beginEditing()
    backingStore.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withString: str)
    edited([.EditedCharacters, .EditedAttributes], range: range, changeInLength: (str as NSString).length - range.length)
    endEditing()
}

override func setAttributes(attrs: [String : AnyObject]?, range: NSRange) {
    beginEditing()
    backingStore.setAttributes(attrs, range: range)
    edited(.EditedAttributes, range: range, changeInLength: 0)
    endEditing()
}

override func setAttributedString(attrString: NSAttributedString) {
    programmaticChange = true
    super.setAttributedString(attrString)
    programmaticChange = false
}

override func processEditing() {
    if (!programmaticChange &&
        (editedMask.rawValue & NSTextStorageEditActions.EditedCharacters.rawValue) == NSTextStorageEditActions.EditedCharacters.rawValue &&
        changeInLength > 0) {
        doSetAttributesForRange(editedRange)
    }
    print(backingStore)
    super.processEditing()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to find something of a workaround though I still have no idea why the crash is happening. It seems to be related to either layout constraints or the size of my rich-text editor's TextView because after I removed the TextView from the storyboard and created it (along with the TextContainer and NSLayoutManager) programatically, the crash no longer occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the following fixed it for me.

Disable scrolling for the UITextView in your XIB file and then programmatically re-enabled it, after you set the custom text storage subclass for the UITextViews Layout Manager.